# Organizing multiple embed codes with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, embed, organized

I have several embed codes on my website, for example:

Embed Code #1:

```
<object width="480" height="385"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/f8Lp2ssd5A9ErAc&hl=en_US&fs=1&"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/f8Lp2A9ErAc&hl=en_US&fs=1&" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="480" height="385"></embed></object>
```

Embed Code #2:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
_qoptions={
qacct:"p-3asdb5E0g6"
};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://edge.quantserve.com/quant.js"></script>
<noscript>
<a href="http://www.quantcast.com/p-3asdb5E0g6" target="_blank"><img src="http://pixel.quantserve.com/pixel/p-3asdb5E0g6.gif" style="display: none;" border="0" height="1" width="1" alt="Quantcast"/></a>
</noscript>
```

and so on..

How do organize them and separate them into an external single js file to keep the markup clean?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I do not see jQuery be of much help
I would either document.write them directly or perhaps store them in an xml file

With document.write it would be something like this (where the noscript is removed since there is no point at all having it in a js file

```
// --- starts jsfile
var embeds = [
'<object width="480" height="385"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/f8Lp2ssd5A9ErAc&hl=en_US&fs=1&"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/f8Lp2A9ErAc&hl=en_US&fs=1&" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="480" height="385"></embed></object>',

'<script type="text/javascript">_qoptions={qacct:"p-3asdb5E0g6"};</script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://edge.quantserve.com/quant.js"></script>'
]; // notice the lack of comma on the last embed
function putEmbed(idx) {
  document.write(embeds[idx]);
}
// ------ end ------
```

and then use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
putEmbed(0); // youtube
</script>
```

and later

```
<script type="text/javascript">
putEmbed(1); // quant
</script>
```